# Error con SetTimeout

Tags: javascript

Estoy tratando de aplicar un estilo con `js` después de varios segundos de la siguiente forma, y en la `consola` me da el siguiente error:

*El if lo tengo así para depurar que no sea problema de la variable paginaCarrito*

**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token if**

```js
var paginaCarrito = window.location;

setTimeout(if (paginaCarrito == paginaCarrito){

  document.getElementById('leo-verticalmenu').style.display='none';
  document.getElementById('left_column').style.display='none';

}, 3000);
```

Comment: setTimeout() recibe una funcion (callback) no una estructura de control

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Como dice JackNavaRow, "setTimeout() recibe una funcion (callback) no una estructura de control"

```js
var paginaCarrito = window.location;

setTimeout(function() {
if (paginaCarrito == paginaCarrito){

  document.getElementById('leo-verticalmenu').style.display='none';
  document.getElementById('left_column').style.display='none';

}}, 3000);
```

```html
<div id="leo-verticalmenu">leo-verticalmenu</div>
<div id="left_column">left_column</div>
```

Comment: Como nota: `setTimeout` también puede recibir una cadena que se evaluará pasado el tiempo indicado. Entonces poner todo lo que tenía antes entre comillas dobles también funcionaría.